# Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH

Tags: git, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm not able to add the cordova barcode plugin. It shows

> Error: git command line tool is not installed: make sure it is
>   accessible on your PATH.

I separately downloaded and installed git and I also set the environment variables `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm;` `C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\git;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;)` 
I also reseted my machine a lot of times but it still shows that error.

```
C:\Users\h117953\myapp>cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeS
canner.git
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git" via git clone

Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on y
our PATH.
    at Object.clone (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\n
ode_modules\cordova-lib\src\gitclone.js:36:25)
    at Object.module.exports.clonePluginGitRepo (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_module

s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\plugins.js:
    42:18)
        at Object.module.exports.clonePluginGit (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\np
    m\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\plugins.js:32:3
    1)
        at C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co
    rdova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:83:28
        at _fulfilled (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\nod
    e_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
    les\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
    e_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
        at C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\
    q.js:509:49
        at flush (C:\Users\h117953\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mod
    ules\q\q.js:108:17)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the output from `echo %PATH%`?

If so I recommened installing GIT to the normal filesystem as a prgram. Not under appdata roaming, and not part of node package manager.

Just use the [default installer for Windows](https://git-scm.com/)